# Golang: multiple definition of CGO ported package

Tags: go, linker, cgo

I have 2 project, the first, name as `A`, there is a submodule `a` imported sqlite3(`github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3`). Another `B` project import `A`'s submodule `a`, and in another submodule `b`, it also import the same sqlite3.

Both `A` and `B` put there imports under `vendor` dir(managed by `govendor`). My Golang version is `go version go1.12 linux/amd64`.

While build `B` (`go build main.go`), throwing following errors(too many, part of them):

```
 /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
 /tmp/go-link-281256755/000029.o: In function `callbackTrampoline':
 /tmp/go-build/_cgo_export.c:25: multiple definition of `callbackTrampoline'
 /tmp/go-link-281256755/000005.o:/tmp/go-build/_cgo_export.c:25: first defined here
 /tmp/go-link-281256755/000029.o: In function `stepTrampoline':
 ...
 /home/xxx/go/src/gitlab.xxxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxxxxx-tools/A/vendor/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/sqlite3.go:129: multiple definition of `_sqlite3_result_text'
 /tmp/go-link-281256755/000009.o:/home/xxx/go/src/gitlab.xxxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxxxxx-tools/A/vendor/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/sqlite3.go:129: first defined here
 /tmp/go-link-281256755/000033.o: In function `_sqlite3_result_blob':
 ...
```

But building `A` works well.  To testing the error, I started following demo, also with `vendor` inited by `govendor`, and build ok.

```
 package main

 import (
   "database/sql"
   "fmt"

   "gitlab.xxxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/A/a"

   _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
 )

 func main() {
   fmt.Println(a.ModuleVariable) // use submodule `a` just like B is doing

   _, _ = sql.Open(`sqlite3`, `test.db`) // use sqlite too
 }
```

I think the compiler first compile `A`'s `sqlite3`, objects are created under `/tmp/go-link-281256755/000005.o` (*but no this dir after building*), then compile `B`'s importing of `sqlite3` and also create a object contains the same-name function, then the compiler find 2 same-name symbols, the linking failed.

How to fix these situation? Is there any golang env settings to avoid these?

---

After I remove the sqlite3 package under `vendor` both of `A` and `B`, they both use the sqlite3 under `~/go/src/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/`, they all build ok. But I can't do these, due to project `A`'s deploy platform, I must put all dependencies under vendor, is there any another option to use multiple import with the same package?

Comment: Perhaps you can use [modules](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules)

Answer (score 3):

For the `cgo`'s issue of linking error "*multiple definition of ...*", the (work-around) solution is dependent on the nature of the linked C codes:

1. If two Go packages link to **the same C codes (libraries)**, you should pass option `--allow-multiple-definition` to the linker (see [`ld` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld)), either via command options

   `go build --ldflags '-extldflags "-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition"'`,

   or via `#cgo` directive in Go source of the packages linking to C codes:

   ```
   //#cgo LDFLAGS: -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition
   import "C"
   ```
2. If two Go packages link to *different C codes* containing **some functions & variables with the same names**, you should *refactor* those C codes:

   - Make sure to put keyword `static` to all declarations whose usage is within that C object only (not intended to be linked to Go nor to other C objects).
   - Find some way to do *name mangling* or put those duplicated identifiers into different *namespaces* (like in C++). It would be better if `cgo` supported some mechanism to do automatic namespacing using Go package name, but until now (2020) you must do it yourself. The C preprocessor's "token pasting" operator `##` may help in this namespacing task. Eg.

     ```
     //File: my_package1.h
     #define NS(id) my_package1_ ## id
     void NS(my_function1)(int);
     void NS(my_function2)(float);
     char NS(my_shared_var);
     ```
3. If you have any **C function definition** in the Go source, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58606884/789095), you must move those definitions into a separate C source file under the same package folder, leaving only declarations in the Go source.